# How to track conversion of a non-redirecting button click?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

There are similar questions already on SO, but mine is a bit different.

I have a scenario where *some* visitors go to a specific page (say /somepage) and on that page is a button leading to some javascript action. The button click will not lead to a change in the current location.

I'm interested in the *conversion*. That is to say: I'm interested in the percentage of people who pressed the button *of those who first visited the page*. I'm not so much interested in how many people clicked the button in total, or how many people requested the page in total.

I know I can report events with actions.

I know I can set a goal to be triggered by actions.

I know there's a thing called "funnel", with which routes can be described that lead up to a goal - but I also know that *they can't be used with goals triggered by actions*.

So what's the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear (to me at least) - you would have to first visit the page to be able to press the button (in that case you do not need a funnel and can use an event based goal). Or do visitors need to look at some other page before they arrive at the page with the button ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff In my scenario there is no second page. The get on a page (linked from off-site) and click or don't click a specific button on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools to create such funnels, your example is simple to implement using http://www.devmetrics.io tool.
You need two different actions, page_opened and button_click. Then you'll get an interface to view your funnels.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- devmetrics.io start -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (doc, inst) {
window.devmetrics = inst; inst.q = inst.q || []; inst.init = function (token) { this.token = token; }; inst.userEvent = function (eventName) { inst.q.push(eventName); };
var a = doc.createElement("script"); a.type = "text/javascript"; a.src = 'http://rawgit.com/devmetrics/devmetrics-js/master/jdevmetrics.js?' + Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() - 1442107445573) / 8640000); var e = doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; e.parentNode.insertBefore(a, e);
})(document, window.devmetrics || []);
devmetrics.init("your-app-id");
</script>
<!-- devmetrics.io end -->

<script>
devmetrics.userEvent('page_opened');
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="devmetrics.userEvent('button_click');">click to send event</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you can use mixpanel.com or kissmetrics for similar tasks.

Comment: I does indeed seem to be a ga weakness. I'm trying mixpanel and devmetrics now.